# How can I replicate data into from one RDS instance to another without using Multi-az?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, clone, amazon-rds, database-replication

I have my production Mysql Aurora RDS instance with no Multi-AZ option enabled.I have a requirement to replicate this production data into another isolated Mysql RDS instance(or perhaps another Mysql server hosted in an EC2 instance) for the purpose of giving access to an ETL tool(Stitch)

I don't have the option to upgrade my RDS to Mult-AZ just to replicate data into another.

What's the best way to achieve this? I can go for both options

1. create another RDS instance and replicate data(if this is possible)
2. Host a mysql server running in an EC2 instance which replicate production RDS data

Comment: Can't you make a snapshot of the RDS instance, and use that snapshot to instantiate a new RDS instance?

Comment: yes I can. but I need to constantly replicate data from the production RDS to this instance. Like every 5 mins for example. is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Then how about a read replica? https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/

Comment: Yeah that would work. in fact i was worried that my production rds instance don't have Mult-AZ enabled. I just checked the config and for my luck It has that feature enabled so that I can go for a read replica easily. @Spiderbro thanks for the support!

Comment: @MahelaWickramasekara RDS read replicas do not require the master to have the Multi-AZ feature enabled. The Multi-AZ feature creates and maintains an *inaccessible* synchronous replica of the master so that you have spare hardware and a live copy of your data that the service will automatically fail over to, in the event of loss or crash of the running/active master.  When you create an RDS replica, there is a brief IO freeze on the master, but this is typically so brief as to go unnoticed.  If you have Multi-AZ enabled, the freeze time is zero because the replica is cloned from the standby.

Comment: If you read something that gave you the impression that RDS read replicas *require* Multi-AZ on the master, please consider providing a link so we can clarify that confusion in an answer for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes it is a misunderstanding from my end. It actually only requires automated backups enabled in the master rds instance. thanks for the detailed explanation Michael! appreciate it

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot and also will it affect the master rds if the read replica goes down for some reason? also we need to create custom views in mysql from the read replica. will that be possible as well?